# How to add author headers on your javascript files in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Hi is there any tool or extensions for visual studio to put author comments or license headers on your javascript files?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following extension, which allow you to insert timestamp, copyright or any information to your file like comment below.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doi.fileheadercomment

In addition, you could also create a custom item template with related author comments or license headers. For more information about How to create Item Templates, please refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396